# Reason behind coil melting

Tags: coil, fault, overheat

Today I managed to melt the ignition coil of my RC engine. First let me describe my circuit, I have also created a diagram, however I could not find all the parts in the designer so I think some textual description makes sense.

I am using an ignition coil (original Zenoah ZN0040, however it does not seem to have a data sheet: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a805fba0-0a5f-4d34-a78e-ab27a98537b0_1.a0ec366348a9c49f8a0f612202795d9c.jpeg) to light up a spark plug for a gasonline engine. The engine has a rotating contact that closes the contact between a contact plate (to solder a cable to) and the engine case. This is the "switch" that will energize the ignition coil that will then create the high voltage output to the spark plug.

I wire my 2S LiPo battery over a capacitor with the + side always connected to the coil and the - side is fixated to the engine case. In parallel I have a 0.47uF 50V capacitor. The contact plate from the rotating contact of the crank shaft is then connected to the negative terminal of the ignition coil, so when the contact closes the coil gets grounded via the engine case to the battery and current flows through the high voltage output of the ignition coil to the spark plug.

I tried to replicate this as best as possible in this image:
[image: Circuit Diagram]

This works great, however I noticed from the beginning that the iron core gets considerably hot (uncomfortable to touch) and according to my research this is not really supposed to happen. Then today I accidentally forgot to disconnect the LiPo batteries and the crank shaft happened to be in a position where it closed the switch, so the coil was permanently producing high voltage output to the spark plug.

Some 15 or 20 minutes later I noticed a loud hissing sound and realized the ignition coil is smoking like crazy and there are sparks (I think) and gas escaping the coil. I immediately disconnected the battery and it also stopped.

So I am wondering what exactly causes this ignition coil to overheat this badly. Sure normally it does not need to constantly produce output, however when the engine is running for hours it still will be producing energy for quite a while. Does anyone have any explanation what the reason could be and is there something I can do in my circuit to prevent this?

Comment: The difference is that when the motor is rotating, it periodically closes the switch and current flows to charge the magnetic field in the coil, and when it does not rotate, and the switch is permanently on so current permanently flows via the coil, perhaps overheating it. However it does not produce high voltage when the switch is closed, it will just heat up.

Comment: Ah right, wenn the switch closes it only can sustain the spark for a very short time, after that it is just current flowing through the inner coil without anything going out, so what "goes out" has to be heat, correct?

Comment: This is why cars have a switch between battery and coils, helpfully labelled "Ignition", often operated by a key. Most small engines generate the low voltage from a magneto coil (usually the primary of that transformer),  which helpfully does nothing when the engine stops and the magnets aren't flying around...

Comment: Technically, it is the opening of that switch which causes the large magnetic field produced by the primary winding to rapidly collapse, which creates the spark on the secondary side.  With it stuck "on", nothing comes out of the secondary; the primary acts as a low-value resistor, gets hot, and burns out.

Comment: If anyone wants to add a answer that has been posted in the comments I am more than willing to accept it

Comment: @rdtsc Ah, very good point, I was kind of surprised about how long the contact breaker is actually engaged. But it makes sense now, it has to charge the field for a while (aided by my condensator) and when it disconnects it all gets discharged to the spark plug.